# How to transfer the whole code of a batch file to another batch file without losing the code from the original? (NOT SIMPLY WRITE TO ANOTHER FILE)

Tags: batch

I have always wanted to be able to write the whole code of one batch file to another batch file so that the code of the other batch file is overwritten by the code of my batch file. I know how to write one statement to another batch file, but that wouldn't help since I need to transfer the whole code of the file that is writing to the other file to the other file and overwrite the code of the other file. I have always used this code, but seems not to be that helpful:

```
@echo My text > example.bat
```

I hope you can tell me a solution to this problem. Thank You!

Comment: What's wrong with `copy myfile.bat example.bat`?

Comment: lol :p That is so funny, how do I Copy and Paste?

Comment: I so feel like writing some code to feel his HDD up with .bat files!